# 'view' does not have a NavController set , NavigationUI with drawerLayout on click

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer

When trying to navigate onclick at drawerLayout header, it says that
`'VIEW' <...> does not have a NavController set at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController`

I was trying to use different methods provided to navigate from controller but nothing seems to work, I guess it's not the way to solve the problem

What I've found at is that it's action related, code below does work

`Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.profileFragmentNav)`

but using id from within code below doesn't:
    `<action android:id="@+id/action_profileFragmentNav_to_chatlistFragment"/>`

Is there a way to make headerLayout work with navController by passing custom view which is nested ?